# Conversion failed when converting nvarchar value to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Scripts TABLE (
                Id INT  IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                Script NVARCHAR(4000)
            )

Insert into @Scripts(Script)
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchFirstName @FirstNameFromUser =''' 
+ @firstname + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
     UNION All
```

and so on ...

As I created Id as identity column and specified `Script` column while inserting data, the string should be inserted in `Script` column only.

But I assume it is trying to insert it in Id column.
I get the following error :

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CallingProcedure, Line 153
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchFirstName 
@FirstNameFromUser ='Simri', @checkbool = 0' to data type int.
```

What seems wrong in my code ?

Edit :

```
Rest of the query looks like this :

Insert into @Scripts(Script)
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchFirstName @FirstNameFromUser =''' + @firstname + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
     UNION All
 select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchMiddleName @MiddleNameFromUser=''' + @MiddleName + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
    UNION ALL
 select  'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchLastName @LastNameFromUser ''' + @Lastname + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
     UNION ALL
 select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchDate @DateFromUser = ''' + @date + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
      UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchMonth @MonthFromUser =''' + @month + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
      UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchYear @YearFromUser = ''' + @year + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
      UNION ALL
 select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchSSN1 @ssnfromuser = ''' + @SSN1 + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
     UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchSSN2 @ssnfromuser =''' + @SSN2 + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
      UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchSSN3 @ssnfromuser =''' + @SSN3 + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
   UNION All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchZIP @ZIPfromuser =''' + @ZIP + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchState @StateFromUsers = ''' + @StateOfResidence + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
 UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchCity @CityfromUser = ''' + @City + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchStreetName @StreetNameFromUser =''' + @Streetname + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchStreetType @StreetTypeFromUser = ''' + @StreetType + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchBuildingNumber @BuildingNumberfromUser = ''' + @BuildingNumber + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
  UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.dbo.MatchAptNumber @AptNumberFromUser =''' + @Aptnumber + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchPatientMaidenLN  @PatientMaidenLN =''' + @patientMaidenLN + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
UNION ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchFatherFirstName @FatherFN =''' + @FatherFN  + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
 Union ALL
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchFathersLastName @FatherLN =''' + @FatherLN + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
 Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchMotherFirstName @MOTHERFN =''' + @MotherFN + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
  Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchMothersLastName @MOtherLN = ''' + @MotherLN + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
 Union All 
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchMothersMaidenLN @MotherMaidenLN =''' + @mothermaidenLN + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
 select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchpatientNickName @patientNickName  =''' + @patientNickName + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchCitizenshp  @citizenship =''' + @Citizenship + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All 
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchNationality  @nationality =''' + @Nationality + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchEthinicity @ethnicity= ''' + @ethnicity + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All  
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchRace @race =''' + @race + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
 Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchReligion @religion = =''' + @Religion + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchPrimaryLanguage  @primarylanguage = ''' + @primarylanguage + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
 Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.Matchpatientmrn @patientmrn =  ''' + @patientmrn + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
   Union All
 select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.Matchhospitalname  @hospitalname = =''' + @hospitalname + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchMedicaidid @medicaidid = =''' + @medicaidid + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.Matchpcpnpi @pcpnpi = ''' + @pcpnpi + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union All
select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.Matchphonenumber @phonenumber = ''' + @phonenumber + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
Union ALL
 select 'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.Matchemail @email = ''' + @email + ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))
```

Comment: I think that you are missing some single quotes between your first name

Comment: Check your `UNION ALL` statements to make sure none of them are selecting an `INT` value.  That will force a cast on the `VARCHAR` columns from your other `UNION` statements.

Comment: @Lamak: Could you please write a query to point where I am doing it wrong ? If I try to insert this same exactly query in nvarchar variable, it works just fine.

Comment: Your composed query: `'Exec POI2Version7.dbo.MatchFirstName 
@FirstNameFromUser ='Simri', @checkbool = 0'` is missing single quotes around `Simri`, it should be `=''Simri''` after you concatenate it

Comment: @Siyual: None of them are . Rest of the Union all statements are exactly the same structure, just calling different proceures.

Comment: @Simran Please post the rest of the query.  The only way you could be getting that error is if one of your `UNION ALL` statements was selecting an `INT` rather than a `VARCHAR`

Comment: @Siyual: I updated the question with complete query. Please check.

Comment: @Simran What are the datatypes of your variables?  If any of them are `INT`, with how they're concatenated, they would generate that error.  Try converting all of your variables to a `VARCHAR`.  (Referring to the `@day`, `@month`, `@year`, etc... data types that look to be `INT` types at first glance.)

Comment: Can you comment out the line beginning 'INSERT' only and execute the rest of the command to see the table of text you are attempting to insert?  I wonder if you have quotes or a newline or something in one of your variables that could impact the insertion command somehow.

Comment: @Siyual: Ah, You are so right. I am pretty sure that's exactly what I needed to do :) Thanks